# How to short circuit when counting duplicated values between two lists?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 lists and I need the fastest way to count/check duplicate elements in list A that match elements in list B.

For instance, if list A is `["A", "B", "C"]` and list B is `["X", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C"]`, my counter should be 2, because there are 2 duplicated elements `("B" & "C")` in B. Since its a boolean method, it should return true whenever any occurrences of A in B are repeated.

I'm avoiding cascading loops and even tried using streams. Although the following code works, I'm still not so sure about its design.
This is how I'm doing it now:

```
class MyPojo {
    int value; String str;
    MyPojo(int value) { this.value = value; };
    /* getters & setters*/ 
}

public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
    List<Integer> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2), 
    new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(4));

    for ( Integer value : forbiddenValues) {
        long count = pojoList.stream()
            .filter( pojoElement -> pojoElement.getValue() == value)
            .count();
        // returns true if in a single iteration count is greater than 1
        if ( count > 1) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @nicomp I want to check for duplicated elements between two lists in the best/fastest/most elegant way, but am not sure about my own choice of design. How can I improve the "hasDuplicates()" method?

Comment: You can short circuit by calling “limit(2)” before “count”.

Comment: But once I call it (limit(2)), what's next? @Aominè

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you. Let me know of you have any questions. You could also use parallel streams if you wanted.

***With Stream API***

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
        List<Integer> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2),
                new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(4));


        long count = pojoList.stream()
                .filter(pojo -> forbiddenValues.contains(pojo.getValue()))
                .map(MyPojo::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(value -> value))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .filter(values -> values.size() > 1)
                .count();

        return count > 1;
    }
```

***Without Streams***

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
        List<Integer> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2),
                new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(4));


        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

        for(int forbidden : forbiddenValues){
            counts.put(forbidden, 0);
        }

        for(MyPojo myPojo : pojoList){
            if(counts.containsKey(myPojo.getValue())){
                int count = counts.get(myPojo.getValue());

                if(count == 1){
                    return true;
                }

                counts.put(myPojo.getValue(), count + 1);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Agreed the second filter is inefficient as it does not short circuit but it gives Lucas an idea of how to go about implementing it using Stream API.

Comment: @Aominè .. I've updated my answer to showcase a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: You operation would be simpler if you did `.map(MyPojo::getValue)`, as then there is no need to call `.getValue()` another time in the `filter` predicate. Further, you have one `> 1` to much, you are checking whether there is more than one duplicate. It’s inefficient anyway, instead of counting, just to find out whether there is a duplicate, you can use `… .values() .stream() .anyMatch(values -> values.size() > 1);`, and if you use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(value -> value), Collectors.counting())`, you’re not collecting into lists when all you want is their size…

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Holger.

Comment: I just noted that I forgot the word “first” in my first sentence, “if you did `.map(MyPojo::getValue)` *first*, …”.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HashSet` to check if the element exist because `contains` is much faster, and following @Aonimé suggestion you can do it like this.

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
        List<Integer> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        Set<Integer> forbiddenValuesSet = new HashSet<>(forbiddenValues);
        List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2),
                new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(4));

        long count = pojoList.stream()
                     .filter(t -> forbiddenValuesSet.contains(t.value)).limit(2).count();
        return count > 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
return pojoList.stream()
        .map(MyPojo::getValue)
        .filter(forbiddenValues::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), value -> false, (a, b) -> true))
        .containsValue(true);
```

- First, map `MyPojo` elements to the value
- Then let only those pass which are contained in `forbiddenValues` (for efficiency, it’s strongly recommended to use a `Set` when the collection becomes bigger)
- collect to a map using the values as key and initially mapping to `false`, but using a *merge* function which will evaluate to `true` for any occurrence of duplicate keys
- if the resulting map contains any `true` value, we had duplicate keys

This is similar to other posted answers, but skips a lot of unnecessary operations. Still, it requires building the entire map before we can query for a duplicate, hence, a loop may still be faster:

```
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
for(MyPojo pojo: pojoList) {
    Integer value = pojo.getValue();
    if(forbiddenValues.contains(value) && !seen.add(value)) return true;
}
return false;
```

`Set.add` returns whether it added the value to the set, i.e. if it was not already contained in the set. So as soon as this method returns `false`, we know that we encountered a duplicate.

Comment: Nice answer. Using a Set instead of  Map as per my answer is a nice clean implementation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest using pure imperative loops instead of streams as the latter more often than not causes more overhead than you might think.

So, in this case I’d start off with nested for each loops before even thinking about Streams.

Further, if you decide to proceed with your stream approach, one improvement you can make is to call `limit(2)` before the `count` eager operation to short circuit where possible.

Comment: Oh, really? I honestly thought nested loops were slower than streams, as well as kind of poor design choices. I'll keep that in mind next time.
Also, I still don't understand how I'd use "limit(2)" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
    List<Integer> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2), 
            new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3),
            new MyPojo(4));

    Map<Integer, Long> map = 
         pojoList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyPojo::getValue, 
                    Collectors.counting()));
    boolean result = 
         forbiddenValues.stream().filter(map::containsKey).map(map::get)
         .anyMatch(count -> count > 1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to add some complexity, though.

Answer (score -1):

This will work.

```
    public static boolean hasDuplicates() {
        List<MyPojo> forbiddenValues = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(1), new MyPojo(2),
            new MyPojo(3));

        List<MyPojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(new MyPojo(0), new MyPojo(2),
        new MyPojo(2), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(3), new MyPojo(4));

        for(MyPojo i : forbiddenValues){
            if(pojoList.contains(i))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyPojo {
    int value; String str;
    MyPojo(int value) { this.value = value; };

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof MyPojo))
            return false;

        MyPojo p = (MyPojo) o;

        return this.value==p.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as it does not check if the pojoList contains duplicate values.

Comment: Read the question again before you say it won't work "I have 2 lists and I need the fastest way to count/check duplicate elements in list A that match elements in list B."

Comment: The question is count the duplicate elements in list B which are in the exception list A. Lucas states this : "if list A is ["A", "B", "C"] and list B is ["X", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C"], my counter should be 2, because there are 2 duplicated elements ("B" & "C") in B". If your logic was correct the answer would be 3 and not 2 as Lucas expects.

Comment: You both are right, if you take the question word for word the answer of [Turan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8675833/turan) is correct. But [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) checks for quality of the whole object not only for the integer value. And when you look at the example code he want to know the count of the duplicate integer values only.